# What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

[The Swift Programming Language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) has the following example:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    var apartment: Apartment?
    deinit { println("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class Apartment {
    let number: Int
    init(number: Int) { self.number = number }
    var tenant: Person?
    deinit { println("Apartment #\(number) is being deinitialized") }
}

var john: Person?
var number73: Apartment?

john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
number73 = Apartment(number: 73)

//From Apple's “The Swift Programming Language” guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)
```

Then when assigning the apartment to the person, they use an exclamation point to "unwrap the instance":

```
john!.apartment = number73
```

What does it mean to "unwrap the instance"? Why is it necessary? How is it different from just doing the following:

```
john.apartment = number73
```

I'm very new to the Swift language.  Just trying to get the basics down.

***UPDATE:***
The big piece of the puzzle that I was missing (not directly stated in the answers - at least not at the time of writing this) is that when you do the following:

```
var john: Person?
```

that does NOT mean that "`john` is of type `Person` and it might be nil", as I originally thought. I was simply misunderstanding that `Person` and `Person?` are completely separate types.  Once I grasped that, all of the other `?`, `!` madness, and the great answers below, made a lot more sense.

Answer (score 551, accepted):

> What does it mean to "unwrap the instance"? Why is it necessary?

As far as I can work out (this is very new to me, too)...

The term "wrapped" implies we should **think of an Optional variable as a present, wrapped in shiny paper, which might (sadly!) be empty**.

When "wrapped", the value of an Optional variable is an enum with two possible values (a little like a Boolean).  This enum describes whether the variable holds a value (`Some(T)`), or not (`None`).

If there is a value, this can be obtained by "unwrapping" the variable (obtaining the `T` from `Some(T)`).

> How is `john!.apartment = number73` different from `john.apartment = number73`?  (Paraphrased)

If you write the name of an Optional variable (eg text `john`, without the `!`), this refers to the "wrapped" enum (Some/None), not the value itself (T).  So `john` isn't an instance of `Person`, and it doesn't have an `apartment` member:

```
john.apartment
// 'Person?' does not have a member named 'apartment'
```

The actual `Person` value can be unwrapped in various ways:

- "forced unwrapping": `john!` (gives the `Person` value if it exists, runtime error if it is nil)
- "optional binding": `if let p = john { println(p) }` (executes the `println` if the value exists)
- "optional chaining": `john?.learnAboutSwift()` (executes this made-up method if the value exists)

I guess you choose one of these ways to unwrap, depending upon what should happen in the nil case, and how likely that is.  This language design forces the nil case to be handled explicitly, which I suppose improves safety over Obj-C (where it is easy to forget to handle the nil case).

**Update**:

The exclamation mark is also used in the syntax for declaring "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals".

In the examples so far, the `john` variable has been declared as `var john:Person?`, and it is an Optional.  If you want the actual value of that variable, you must unwrap it, using one of the three methods above.

If it were declared as `var john:Person!` instead, the variable would be an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional (see the section with this heading in Apple's book).  There is no need to unwrap this kind of variable when accessing the value, and `john` can be used without additional syntax.  But Apple's book says:

> Implicitly unwrapped optionals should not be used when there is a possibility of a variable becoming nil at a later point. Always use a normal optional type if you need to check for a nil value during the lifetime of a variable.

**Update 2**:

The article "[Interesting Swift Features](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-20-interesting-swift-features.html)" by Mike Ash gives some motivation for optional types.  I think it is great, clear writing.

**Update 3**:

Another useful article about the *implicitly unwrapped optional* use for the exclamation mark: "[Swift and the Last Mile](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2014/06/14/swift-and-the-last-mile/)" by Chris Adamson.  The article explains that this is a pragmatic measure by Apple used to declare the types used by their Objective-C frameworks which might contain nil.  Declaring a type as optional (using `?`) or implicitly unwrapped (using `!`) is "a tradeoff between safety and convenience".  In the examples given in the article, Apple have chosen to declare the types as implicitly unwrapped, making the calling code more convenient, but less safe.

Perhaps Apple might comb through their frameworks in the future, removing the uncertainty of implicitly unwrapped ("probably never nil") parameters and replacing them with optional ("certainly could be nil in particular [hopefully, documented!] circumstances") or standard non-optional ("is never nil") declarations, based on the exact behaviour of their Objective-C code.

Comment: I'm not sure about this explanation.  If you just run the code without the ! it still returns the actual value.  Maybe the ! is for speed?

Comment: OK.  So the docs talk about using ! when you know for sure it can be unwrapped.  But you can run the code fine without it (a forth option for your list - implicit unwrapping) AND without checking first. You get back the value or nil if nil. But if you know for sure that it is not nil then use !......but I still can't see why you would do this?

Comment: Hi @RichardWashington - I've added an update to my answer which hopefully clarifies some of this.

Comment: Update 3 is exactly what I'm looking for. Before reading it I thought Apple was lying when they returned something like NSURLCredential! which actually could be nil.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer @Ashley. After reading this answer and some of Apple's example swift code, it really seems to me that in this tradeoff between safety and productivity, usually it's best to be on the safer side. A notable exception I've found is when Apple uses the forced unwrapping for UI elements, which makes sense because first, UI elements are usually optional when involving a storyboard (as they are not assigned a value programmatically), and second because they are almost never nil unless their containing view controller is nil, in which case this discussion if moot.

Comment: Here's another way to think about it: Let's say Amy wants to confirm that she has John's number in her phone. To do this, she looks up John's name in the phone book. If it's not there, she can do one of two things: she can assume the number she has is different from John's number, or she can go into a panic because she KNEW John was in the phonebook.

Comment: It seems like the `!` is pointless unless it's used on a `?` declared var, I think they could have made things simpler by not requiring an optional var to be declared with `!` and just make it implicit like every other language

Answer (score 130):

Here is what I think is the difference:

```
var john: Person?
```

Means john can be nil

```
john?.apartment = number73
```

The compiler will interpret this line as:

```
if john != nil {
    john.apartment = number73
}
```

While

```
john!.apartment = number73
```

The compiler will interpret this line as simply:

```
john.apartment = number73
```

Hence, using `!` will unwrap the if statement, and make it run faster, but if john is nil, then a runtime error will happen.

So wrap here doesn't mean it is memory wrapped, but it means it is code wrapped, in this case it is wrapped with an if statement, and because Apple pay close attention to performance in runtime, they want to give you a way to make your app run with the best possible performance.

**Update:**

Getting back to this answer after 4 years, as I got the highest reputations from it in Stackoverflow :)
I misunderstood a little the meaning of unwrapping at that time. Now after 4 years I believe the meaning of unwrapping here is to expand the code from its original compact form. Also it means removing the vagueness around that object, as we are not sure by definition if it is nil or not. Just like the [answer of Ashley above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24020951/7487335), think about it as a present which could contain nothing in it. But I still think that the unwrapping is code unwrapping and not memory based unwrapping as using enum.

Comment: In my playground john.apartment = number73 does not compile, you must specify john?.apartment = number73

Comment: @ChuckPinkert is right, the 4th line should be edited to john?.apartment = number73, nice answer though!

Comment: john.apartment = number73 gives error:
value of Optional type 'Person?' not unwrapped: did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: The unwrapping has nothing to do w.r.t performance. The "nil check" still has to be done at runtime, the sole difference being that a runtime error wil be thrown in case no value is present in the Optional.

Answer (score 71):

TL;DR

What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?

> The exclamation mark effectively says, “I know that this optional
>   definitely has a value; please use it.” This is known as forced unwrapping of the optional’s value:

Example

```
let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
print(possibleString!) // requires an exclamation mark to access its value
// prints "An optional string."

let assumedString: String! = "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."
print(assumedString)  // no exclamation mark is needed to access its value
// prints "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_399

Comment: Your answer is great because I understand _what_ is going on now. What I don't understand is why implicitly unwrapped optionals exist. Why create something defined as an implicitly unwrapped optional String, rather than a regular String type? Their usage thereafter is the same. What am I missing?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true anymore. In a Swift 5 repl, if I do `let f: String! = "hello"` and then `print(f)`, the output is `Optional("hello")` instead of just `"hello"`.

Answer (score 37):

If john were an optional var (declared thusly)

```
var john: Person?
```

then it would be possible for john to have no value (in ObjC parlance, nil value)

The exclamation point basically tells the compiler "I know this has a value, you don't need to test for it". If you didn't want to use it, you could conditionally test for it:

```
if let otherPerson = john {
    otherPerson.apartment = number73
}
```

The interior of this will only evaluate if john has a value.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I now understand *what* the exclamation mark says, I'm still trying to wrap my head around *why*... You said it tells the compiler "I know this has a value, you don't need to test for it". What does it buy me when the compiler doesn't test for it? Without the exclamation point, is the compiler going to throw an error (I don't have an environment, yet, where I can test Swift)? Is the ! 100% necessary for all optional vars? If so, why did Apple bother with it, as opposed to just making it so the *lack* of ! means "I know this has a value, you don't need to test for it"?

Comment: "is the compiler going to throw an error" - no it still works fine returning the value as expected.  I don't get this. Is the ! just for speed when you are sure maybe?

Comment: In fact later on the docs talk about implicitly unwrapped optionals using the below example:

`“let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
println(possibleString!) // requires an exclamation mark to access its value
// prints "An optional string.”`

But it works fine with no !.  Something seems odd here.

Comment: @RichardWashington You're confused for good reason! The examples in the docs are leaving some things out, and are misleading because all they do is use println. Apparently, there are at least a couple of instances where unwrapping of optionals is not required. One is when using println. Another is when using string interpolation. So, maybe println and string interpolation are unwrapping under the covers? Maybe someone has more insight on this. Looking at the Xcode6 Beta header definitions didn't reveal to me anything about this magic.

Comment: Yes, I get that `John?` and `John` are two different types.  One is of type Optional Person and the other Type Person. Optional Person needs to be unwrapped before you can get Person out.

But as you say, this seems to happen at least in these circumstances without having to actually do anything.  This seems to make the ! redundant.

Unless the ! is ALWAYS optional but a suggested thing to do to catch compile time errors.  Kind of like assigning vars/lets to a particular type can be explicit `let John: Person = ...` but can also be inferred `let John = ...`.

Answer (score 35):

Some big picture perspective to add to the other useful but more detail-centric answers:

In Swift, the exclamation point appears in several contexts:

- Forced unwrapping: `let name = nameLabel!.text`
- Implicitly unwrapped optionals: `var logo: UIImageView!`
- Forced casting: `logo.image = thing as! UIImage`
- Unhandled exceptions: `try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, [])`

Every one of these is a different language construct with a different meaning, but they all have three important things in common:

#### 1. Exclamation points circumvent Swift’s compile-time error handling checks.

When you use `!` in Swift, you are essentially saying, “Hey, compiler, I know you think an error *could* happen here, but I *know* with total certainty that it never will.”

(**Edit to clarify:** The force-unwrapping `!` is still “safe” in the language design sense that is it *not undefined behavior*, and is guaranteed to crash in a clean, predictable way (unlike dereferencing a null pointer in C or C++). It is not “safe” in the app developer sense that the language makes sure your app won’t suddenly fail because of your bad assumptions.)

Not all valid code fits into the box of Swift’s compile-time type system — or *any* language’s static type checking, for that matter. There are situations where you can logically prove that an error will never happen, but you can’t prove it *to the compiler*. That’s why Swift’s designers added these features in the first place.

However, whenever you use `!`, you’re ruling out having a recovery path for an error, which means that…

#### 2. Exclamation points are potential crashes.

An exclamation point also says, “Hey Swift, I am *so* certain that this error can never happen that it’s better for you to *crash my whole app* than it is for me to code a recovery path for it.”

That’s a dangerous assertion. It *can* be the correct one: in mission-critical code where you have thought hard about your code’s invariants, it may be that bogus output is worse than a crash.

However, when I see `!` in the wild, it's rarely used so mindfully. Instead, it too often means, “this value was optional and I didn’t really think too hard about *why* it could be nil or how to properly handle that situation, but adding `!` made it compile … so my code is correct, right?”

Beware the arrogance of the exclamation point. Instead…

#### 3. Exclamation points are best used sparingly.

Every one of these `!` constructs has a `?` counterpart that forces you to deal with the error/nil case:

- Conditional unwrapping: `if let name = nameLabel?.text { ... }`
- Optionals: `var logo: UIImageView?`
- Conditional casts: `logo.image = thing as? UIImage`
- Nil-on-failure exceptions: `try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, [])`

If you are tempted to use `!`, it is always good to consider carefully why you are not using `?` instead. Is crashing your program really the best option if the `!` operation fails? **Why is that value optional/failable?**

Is there a reasonable recovery path your code could take in the nil/error case? If so, code it.

If it can’t possibly be nil, if the error can never happen, then is there a reasonable way to rework your logic so that the compiler knows that? If so, do it; your code will be less error-prone.

There are times when there is no reasonable way to handle an error, and **ignoring the error — and thus proceeding with wrong data — would be *worse* than crashing**. *Those* are the times to use force unwrapping.

I periodically search my entire codebase for `!` and audit every use of it. Very few usages stand up to scrutiny. (As of this writing, the entire Siesta framework has exactly [two](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/0a23609737282b2834b770172410dde08e57e8a7/Source/Resource.swift#L422) [instances](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/blob/0a23609737282b2834b770172410dde08e57e8a7/Source/Resource.swift#L438) of it.)

That’s not to say you should *never* use `!` in your code — just that you should use it *mindfully*, and never make it the default option.

Comment: `func isSubscriptionActive(receiptData: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        if(receiptData == nil) { return false; }
        return (hasValidTrial(receiptData!) || isNotExpired(receiptData!)) && isNotCancelled(receiptData!)
    }`

Given 3. is there a better way to write it?

Comment: You can say `func isSubscriptionActive(receiptData: NSDictionary?) -> Bool { guard let nonNilReceiptData = receiptData else { return false} return (hasValidTrial(nonNilReceiptData) || isNotExpired(nonNilReceiptData)) && isNotCancelled(nonNilReceiptData) }`

Comment: Exclamation marks don't circumvent any safety checks. You get a _guaranteed_ crash if the optional is nil. The optional is _always_ checked. It's just a very brutal way to make a safety check.

Comment: @gnasher729 As the answer states, it circumvents the _compile-time_ safety checks in favor of a safe _runtime_ failure.

Answer (score 25):

`john` is an optional `var` and it can contain a `nil` value. To ensure that the value isn't nil use a `!` at the end of the `var` name.

From documentation

**“Once you’re sure that the optional does contain a value, you can access its underlying value by adding an exclamation mark (!) to the end of the optional’s name. The exclamation mark effectively says, “I know that this optional definitely has a value; please use it.”**

Another way to check non nil value is (optional unwrapping)

```
    if let j = json {
        // do something with j
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I had seen that in the documentation, but it still seems unnecessary... as, to me, `john.apartment = number73` also says "I know that this optional definitely has a value; please use it."...

Comment: Yes it does, but the point is that by default Swift tries to catch errors at compile time. If you know or think you know that this variable cannot contain nil you can remove that check by using the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 16):

Here are some examples:

```
var name:String = "Hello World"
var word:String?
```

Where `word` is an optional value. means it may or may not contain a value.

```
word = name
```

Here `name` has a value so we can assign it

```
var cow:String = nil
var dog:String!
```

Where `dog` is forcefully unwrapped means it must contain a value

```
dog = cow
```

The application will crash because we are assign `nil` to unwrapped

Comment: `var c:Int = nil` will get: "Nil cannot initialize specified type 'int'"

Answer (score 14):

In this case...

var John: Person!

it means, that initially John will have nil value, it will be set and once set will never be nil-led again. Therefore for convenience I can use the easier syntax for accessing an optional var because this is an "Implicitly unwrapped optional"

Comment: Thank you.  I'd also found the following link that explains this.  This kind of type is called an "implicitly unwrapped option". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122601/swift-variable-decorations-with-and

Answer (score 5):

If you've come from a C-family language, you will be thinking "pointer to object of type X which might be the memory address 0 (NULL)", and if you're coming from a dynamically typed language you'll be thinking "Object which is probably of type X but might be of type undefined". Neither of these is actually correct, although in a roundabout way the first one is close.

The way you should be thinking of it is as if it's an object like:

```
struct Optional<T> {
   var isNil:Boolean
   var realObject:T
}
```

When you're testing your optional value with `foo == nil` it's really returning `foo.isNil`, and when you say `foo!` it's returning `foo.realObject` with an assertion that `foo.isNil == false`. It's important to note this because if `foo` actually is nil when you do `foo!`, that's a runtime error, so typically you'd want to use a conditional let instead unless you are very sure that the value will not be nil. This kind of trickery means that the language can be strongly typed without forcing you to test if values are nil everywhere.

In practice, it doesn't truly behave like that because the work is done by the compiler. At a high level there is a type `Foo?` which is separate to `Foo`, and that prevents funcs which accept type `Foo` from receiving a nil value, but at a low level an optional value isn't a true object because it has no properties or methods; it's likely that in fact it is a pointer which may by NULL(0) with the appropriate test when force-unwrapping.

There other situation in which you'd see an exclamation mark is on a type, as in:

```
func foo(bar: String!) {
    print(bar)
}
```

This is roughly equivalent to accepting an optional with a forced unwrap, i.e.:

```
func foo(bar: String?) {
    print(bar!)
}
```

You can use this to have a method which technically accepts an optional value but will have a runtime error if it is nil. In the current version of Swift this apparently bypasses the is-not-nil assertion so you'll have a low-level error instead. Generally not a good idea, but it can be useful when converting code from another language.

Answer (score 3):

The ! means that you are force unwrapping the object the ! follows.  More info can be found  in Apples documentation, which can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with C#, this is like Nullable types which are also declared using a question mark:

```
Person? thisPerson;
```

And the exclamation mark in this case is equivalent to accessing the .Value property of the nullable type like this:

```
thisPerson.Value
```

Answer (score 2):

John is an optional Person, meaning it can hold a value or be nil.

```
john.apartment = number73
```

is used if john is not an optional. Since john is never nil we can be sure it won't call apartment on a nil value. While

```
john!.apartment = number73
```

promises the compiler that john is not nil then unwraps the optional to get john's value and accesses john's apartment property. Use this if you know that john is not nil. If you call this on a nil optional, you'll get a runtime error.

The documentation includes a nice example for using this where convertedNumber is an optional.

```
if convertedNumber {
    println("\(possibleNumber) has an integer value of \(convertedNumber!)")
} else {
    println("\(possibleNumber) could not be converted to an integer")
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that if john is nil, and I go `john.apartment = number73`, that WON'T result in an error unless I put a '!' after john?

Comment: If john is an optional you must use the exclamation point to access its properties because the compiler must know that it isn't nil. If it is not an optional you can't use the exclamation point.

Comment: If I must use an exclamation point for ALL optional vars, then why did Apple even bother with it, as opposed to making it so the *lack* of an exclamation point means the same thing?  It seems like needless bloat... Or is there a case where it makes sense to NOT use an exclamation point with an optional var?

Comment: you use the exclamation point when you need the optional to be not nil. Like in the case with accessing properties of john. you could do something like var jack: Person? = john where jack is also an optional or var jack: Person = john! where jack is a Person and is not nil

Comment: Right but, in the original example, doesn't the fact that I'm dereferencing the `john` optional tell the compiler that I need it to be non-nil?... And in your `var jack: Person = john!` example, doesn't the lack of a ? after Person tell the compiler that you need `john` to be non-nil? Overall, the `!` just seems seems kind of redundant... It still feels like I'm missing something on the "why" part of `!`...

Comment: "f john is an optional you must use the exclamation point to access its properties" - actually you don't need to.  Take it off and see for yourself - it still returns 123 as expected.

Comment: In fact later on the docs talk about implicitly unwrapped optionals using the below example:

`“let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
println(possibleString!) // requires an exclamation mark to access its value
// prints "An optional string.”`

But it works fine with no !.  Something seems odd here.

Answer (score 2):

In objective C variables with no value were equal to 'nil'(it was also possible to use 'nil' values same as 0 and false), hence it was possible to use variables in conditional statements (Variables having values are same as 'TRUE' and those with no values were equal to 'FALSE').

Swift provides type safety by providing 'optional value'. i.e. It prevents errors formed from assigning variables of different types.

So in Swift, only booleans can be provided on conditional statements.

```
var hw = "Hello World"
```

Here, even-though 'hw' is a string, it can't be used in an if statement like in objective C.

```
//This is an error

if hw

 {..}
```

For that it needs to be created as,

```
var nhw : String? = "Hello World"

//This is correct

if nhw

 {..}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ! at the end of an object says the object is an optional and to unwrap if it can otherwise returns a nil. This is often used to trap errors that would otherwise crash the program.

Answer (score 2):

In Short (!):
After you have declare a variable and that you are certain the variable is holding a value.

```
let assumedString: String! = "Some message..."
let implicitString: String = assumedString
```

else you would have to do this on every after passing value...

```
let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
let forcedString: String = possibleString! // requires an exclamation mark
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Googlers:**

```swift
john!.department
```

...tells compiler:

- I know `john` is optional
- Use it as if it has value
- Just crash if it does not

In production, use `guard let` or `if let` to deal with the situation of no-value and void hard crashes.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, exclamation marks mean an optional is being unwrapped. An optional is a variable that can have a value or not -- so you can check if the variable is empty, using an if let statement [as shown here](https://medium.com/arthurs-coding-tips/optionals-in-swift-c94fd231e7a4), and then force unwrap it. If you force unwrap an optional that is empty though, your program will crash, so be careful! Optionals are declared by putting a question mark at the end of an explicit assignment to a variable, for example I could write:

```
var optionalExample: String?
```

This variable has no value. If I were to unwrap it, the program would crash and Xcode would tell you you tried to unwrap an optional with a value of nil.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

***IN SIMPLE WORDS***

**USING Exclamation mark indicates that variable must consists non nil value (it never be nil)**

Answer (score 1):

The entire story begins with a feature of swift called optional vars.
These are the vars which may have a value or may not have a value. In general swift doesn't allow us to use a variable which isn't initialised, as this may lead to crashes or unexpected reasons and also server a placeholder for backdoors.
Thus in order to declare a variable whose value isn't initially determined we use a '?'. 
When such a variable is declared, to use it as a part of some expression one has to unwrap them before use, unwrapping is an operation through which value of a variable is discovered this applies to objects. Without unwrapping if you try to use them you will have compile time error.
To unwrap a variable which is an optional var, exclamation mark "!" is used.

Now there are times when you know that such optional variables will be assigned values by system for example or your own program but sometime later , for example UI outlets, in such situation instead of declaring an optional variable using a question mark "?" we use "!".

Thus system knows that this variable which is declared with "!" is optional right now and has no value but will receive a value in later in its lifetime.

Thus exclamation mark holds two different usages, 
1. To declare a variable which will be optional and will receive value definitely later 
2. To unwrap an optional variable before using it in an expression.

Above descriptions avoids too much of technical stuff, i hope.

Answer (score 1):

If you use it as an optional, it unwraps the optional and sees if something is there. If you use it in an if-else statement is is code for NOT. For example,

```
if (myNumber != 3){
 // if myNumber is NOT 3 do whatever is inside these brackets.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An Optional variable may contain a value or may be not

case 1: `var myVar:String? = "Something"`

case 2: `var myVar:String? = nil`

now if you ask myVar!, you are telling compiler to return a value in case 1 it will return `"Something"`

in case 2 it will crash.

Meaning ! mark will force compiler to return a value, even if its not there. thats why the name **Force Unwrapping**.

Comment: @Moritz.  I dont know is it so ? Cant i answer if a question is already answered? Am i causing any problem or is there anything wrong in my answer ? i dont understand Why are you downvoting it for answering it correctly? I tried to answer based on my understanding of the concept. i think some people will find it helpful for clear and easy explanation.

Comment: @Moritz Now this is constructive. You should have told me this correction in the first place, if this was the reason. thanks for the feedback. i have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple the Optional variable allows nil to be stored.

var str : String? = nil

str = "Data"

To convert Optional to the Specific DataType, We unwrap the variable using the keyword "!"

func get(message : String){
   return
}

get(message : str!)  // Unwapped to pass as String
```

Comment: Please don't write answers that are not adding anything that has not already been covered by previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

**ASK YOURSELF**

- Does the type **`person?`** have an `apartment` member/property?  OR
- Does the type **`person`** have an `apartment` member/property?

If you can't answer this question, then continue reading:

<sub>To understand you may need super-basic level of understanding of **Generics**. See [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115960/swift-tutorial-introduction-to-generics). A lot of things in Swift are written using Generics. Optionals included</sub>

The code below has been made available from [this Stanford video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrTTCaL2xQM). Highly recommend you to watch the first 5 minutes

## An Optional is an enum with only 2 cases

```
enum Optional<T>{
    case None
    case Some(T)
}

let x: String? = nil //actually means:

let x = Optional<String>.None
```

---

```
let x :String? = "hello" //actually means:

let x = Optional<String>.Some("hello")
```

---

```
var y = x! // actually means:

switch x {
case .Some(let value): y = value
case .None: // Raise an exception
}
```

## Optional binding:

```
let x:String? = something
if let y = x {
    // do something with y
}
//Actually means:

switch x{
case .Some(let y): print)(y) // or whatever else you like using 
case .None: break
}
```

when you say `var john: Person?` You actually mean such:

```
enum Optional<Person>{
case .None
case .Some(Person)
}
```

Does the above enum have any *property* named `apartment`? Do you see it anywhere? It's **not** there at all! However if you unwrap it ie do `person!` then you can ... what it does under the hood is : `Optional<Person>.Some(Person(name: "John Appleseed"))`

---

Had you defined `var john: Person` instead of: `var john: Person?` then you would have no longer needed to have the `!` used, because `Person` itself does have a member of `apartment`

---

As a future discussion on why using `!` to unwrap is sometimes not recommended see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39455123)

Comment: Using the _actual slides_ above is possibly copyright infringement: _"... Stanford University does retain copyright to all content in our iTunes U collection."_, from [http://itunes.stanford.edu](http://itunes.stanford.edu). Probably better to answer, in you own words, the content you learned from the course that you perceive to answer this question (and instead of using the slides, rather _quote_ relevant parts of them in code form, with references, naturally).

Comment: @dfri Stanford itself has shared their slides on iTunes U for free. I have seen their slides on multiple answers and their slides being shared on internet freely. I have seen many times people copy/paste from blogs and attributing to them. This is possibly the first time I am seeing someone countering the approach. I have also attributed to them. Anyhow, thanks for your concern.

Comment: Your argument is [_argumentum ad populum_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum). Anyway, [I don't believe Stanford will come here and enforce DMCA rights](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/dealing-with-posts-plagiarising-from-copyrighted-sources), but its always better if your answers are in your own words _based on official/valid sources_, and not in the form of copying those sources outright as above; especially when we talk about copyrighted slides: again, better to quote the content of the slides in code blocks (images of code is generally a no-no here at SO!).

Comment: From the link you sent: "From a copyright perspective, I don't think that's true. Instead, they have to remove infringing content as soon as the copyright owner requests it. The difference is that some owners encourage the spread of their content in this manner, often in the simple hope of gaining notoriety."---I don't mean to say you're wrong rather I really don't know if what I am doing is correct or what you are saying is correct.

Comment: The meta post I linked to just describes SO:s approach to this: a post such as this one will naturally not be removed if some random user reports it as copyright infringement: only if e.g. a Stanford rep. were to come here and as the post to be removed would SO _need to_ enforce it. Hence I wrote _"**I don't believe** Stanford will come here and enforce DMCA rights, ..."_. My point above is that I believe this to be possibly copyright infringement (which I believe to be wrong), but naturally no one will ever enforce this. ...

Comment: But this aside, posting questions or answers which contain images of code is [upright discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) for a number of reasons. To wrap it up: I've tried to point out with these comments that I believe this answer, in its current form, is not entirely as good as it could be, due to two major reasons (copyrighted slides, image of code). Naturally no one, including myself, will do anything about this, I'm simply pointing it our for future reference (or possibly encouraging you to edit this post with quote by code blocks instead). Agreed, iTunes U! :)

Comment: @dfri removed images