# How do I make a class conform to a protocol in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to make a class conform to a protocol in Swift in order to implement a delegate. How would I do so?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
class YourClass: SuperClassIfAny, FirstProtocol, SecondProtocol {
}
```

Note, though, that some protocols **require** you to implement delegate methods. For instance, `UITableViewDataSource` **requires** you to implement

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
```

If those are not implemented by the class conforming to the protocol, Xcode will give you a compile error (always check the protocol declaration, Cmd + Click will show you what methods you **must** implement).

Comment: Wish it would show a more useful error than: 'does not conform to protocol'

Comment: Agree, I actually spent some time trying to find why it wasn't compiling. I think this is a good thing, though, prevents you from stupid errors. 

It'd be cool if they added a more descriptive error, still :-P

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 6 beta 7 changed the protocol slightly for UITableViewDataSource to match the following syntax on the two required implementations:

6b7 : [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell!
```

compared to 6b6

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell
```

Of key difference is that UITableView, NSIndexPath and UITableViewCell are no longer '[Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)'

Comment: -1;                                                                                                this doesn't remotely answer the question.