# Issue setting CABasicAnimation delegate in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cabasicanimation, swift3

I'm getting the following error

> Cannot assign value of type 'StarButton' to type
>   'CAAnimationDelegate?'

on the last line of this CABasicAnimation block:

```
 let fillCircle = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
 fillCircle.toValue = 0
 fillCircle.duration = 0.3
 fillCircle.setValue(notFavoriteKey, forKey: starKey)
 fillCircle.delegate = self // this is where the error is thrown
```

`self` is a custom UIButton class. This wasn't an issue in previous versions of Swift... any suggestions on a solution?

**UPDATE**

Here is a downloadable link to the source file for the StarButton class for best reference:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvc2sky05f4p3au/StarButton.swift?dl=0

Comment: Are you sure it conforms to the delegate protocol?

Comment: `UIButton` from the Apple Docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/) doesn't conform to `CAAnimationDelegate`. Did you explicitly say that your subclass was a delegate? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024466/how-do-i-make-a-class-conform-to-a-delegate-in-swift

Comment: @Fogmeister well this is part of an open source component I grabbed & after examining the file it doesn't seem to have any protocol's.. however this worked perfectly fine in swift 2.xx

Comment: @Doc well this is part of an open source component I grabbed & after examining the file it doesn't seem to have any protocol's.. however this worked perfectly fine in swift 2.xx

Comment: Maybe Swift 3 made protocol casts strict? Anyways you should still add the protocol; if the class supports being a delegate it should say so in the declaration

Comment: how should I go about adding the protocol? @Doc

Comment: can you post the StarButton class?

Comment: Adding a protocol is like adding another superclass; if you have something like `class StarButton: UIButton`, replace with `class StarButton: UIButton, CABasicAnimationDelegate`

Comment: check updated question @ChristianAbella

Comment: check updated question @Doc

Comment: Just replace the line `class StarButton: UIButton {` with `class StarButton: UIButton, CAAnimationDelegate {`. You might need to import CoreAnimation also

Comment: that did it! haha, wow something that seemed so trivial @Doc

Answer (score 10):

As @Doc mentioned in the comments above, the solution is to replace

```
class StarButton: UIButton {
```

with

```
class StarButton: UIButton, CAAnimationDelegate {
```

It would seem that the CAAnimationDelegate protocol is no longer implied and must be specified explicitly.