# How do I address the “There was a problem running this page” message in Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, scenekit, swift-playground

I am trying to make something with SceneKit for the WWDC Student Challenge, which requires my project be in a Swift playground.  I keep getting the message that says “There was a problem running this page.”  It offers no error messages.  It just suggests that check my code or start over.  I have tried removing pieces of code individually, but I cannot locate the source of this issue.  I have also tried running it in man Xcode playground, which offered the warning of, and I quote, “The playground could not continue running because the playground source did”.  I am stuck.  What is wrong with my code.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore 
import PlaygroundSupport

class GameScene: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
    var primaryView: SCNView!
    var primaryScene: SCNScene!
    var cameraNode: SCNNode!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        sceneAndViewInit()
        cameraInit()
        createGround()
        moonInit()
    }
    
    func createGround() {
        var ground = SCNBox(width: 200, height: 1, length: 200, chamferRadius: 0)
        var groundPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: ground, options: nil) 
        var groundNode = SCNNode(geometry: ground)
        ground.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
        ground.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
        groundNode.position = SCNVector3(0, -6, 0)
        groundNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: groundPhysicsShape)
        primaryScene.rootNode.addChildNode(groundNode)
    }
    
    func sceneAndViewInit() {
        primaryView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 300))
        primaryView.allowsCameraControl = true
        primaryView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        
        primaryScene = SCNScene()
        
        primaryView.scene = primaryScene
        primaryView.isPlaying = true
    }
    
    func cameraInit() {
        var cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 2)
        cameraNode.camera?.fieldOfView = 65
        cameraNode.camera?.wantsHDR = false
        primaryScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }
    
    func moonInit() {
        let moonScene = SCNScene(named: "Moon.scn")
        var moonNode = moonScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Sphere", recursively: true)
        var moonPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: moonNode!, options: nil)
        moonNode?.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
        moonNode?.scale = SCNVector3(1, 1, 1)
        moonNode?.name = "Moon"
        moonNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: moonPhysicsShape)
        primaryScene.rootNode.addChildNode(moonNode!)
    }
    
    func renderer(_ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        print(time)
    }
}

let gameScene = GameScene()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = gameScene
```

(“Moon.scn” is a file that I have in the resources/files section along with its texture, and I still have the issue without any of the moon related code.)

Comment: Did you find a solution? Running into the same problem.

Comment: I have added an answer explaining what fixed for me and what I know about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to address this issue.  However, I can only offer you a round-ish idea of what the issue is and how to fix it.
The problem seems to be with the variable declarations at the top of the class.

```
var primaryView: SCNView!
var primaryScene: SCNScene!
var cameraNode: SCNNode!
```

The exclamation mark following the type indicates that the variable is an `implicitly-unwrapped optional` (I am quoting from [this Stack Overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286638/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-in-a-property-in-swift-language) that explains what this is in more depth), but more-or-less the variable will automatically force unwrap whenever it is used.  I have a more of a working knowledge of Swift than a technical one, so my guess is that when a `GameScene` object is created a synthetic initializer tries to set up these variables, it, for some reason, needs to read from the variables, gets `nil`, and cannot continue.

The solution appears to be putting the values of the variables in their initial declaration (There might be a better solution, but this at least works in my testing.), so that they are not `nil` for the initializer.  Now the reason that I cannot fully explain the issue here is that this only seems to be necessary for the `SCNScene` variable.  I don't really know why this is the case.

Code (`***` mark important comments):

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore 
import PlaygroundSupport

class GameScene: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
    var primaryView: SCNView!// = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 300)) //***This seems to work for reasons beyond me with the implicitly-unwrapped optional***
    var primaryScene = SCNScene() //***The implicitly unwrapped optional is removed here***
    var cameraNode = SCNNode() //***The implicitly unwrapped optional is removed here (I am not sure if that is necessary but it probably good practice not to use it anywhere intros code.  I use it earlier to demonstrate its weird complexities.)***
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        sceneAndViewInit()
        cameraInit()
        createGround()
        //moonInit() ***I removed this for simplicity in the answer***
    }
    
    func createGround() {
        var ground = SCNBox(width: 200, height: 1, length: 200, chamferRadius: 0)
        var groundPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: ground, options: nil) 
        var groundNode = SCNNode(geometry: ground)
        ground.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
        ground.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
        groundNode.position = SCNVector3(0, -6, 0)
        groundNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: groundPhysicsShape)
        primaryScene.rootNode.addChildNode(groundNode)
    }
    
    func sceneAndViewInit() {
        primaryView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 300))
        primaryView.allowsCameraControl = true
        primaryView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        
        //primaryScene = SCNScene() ***This is not necessary when it is declared above***
        
        self.primaryView.scene = primaryScene
        //primaryView.isPlaying = true
        
        self.view = primaryView //***I realized later you need this bit of code or the program will only display a blank screen***
    }
    
    func cameraInit() {
        //var cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 2)
        cameraNode.camera?.fieldOfView = 65
        cameraNode.camera?.wantsHDR = false
        primaryScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }
    
    func moonInit() {
        let moonScene = SCNScene(named: "Moon.scn")
        var moonNode = moonScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Sphere", recursively: true)
        var moonPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: moonNode!, options: nil)
        moonNode?.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
        moonNode?.scale = SCNVector3(1, 1, 1)
        moonNode?.name = "Moon"
        moonNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: moonPhysicsShape)
        primaryScene.rootNode.addChildNode(moonNode!)
    }
    
    func renderer(_ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        print(time)
    }
}

let gameScene = GameScene()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = gameScene
```

One final note:
The `self.view = primaryView` code is really important.  I make a note about in the full code, but I have found this way too hard to locate on the internet.  I think this has to do with `UIViewController` (I don't know much about `UIKit` at all.), but either `SceneKit` or `UIKit` just displays a blank screen if you do now have that bit of code.  If you don't figure out that these are separate issues they are really hard to decipher.

Answer (score 5):

To view the full error message, go to  Settings app -> Playgrounds -> turn on Authoring Debug Mode. This doesn't directly solve the issue but it's a lot more helpful for locating errors.

[image: Settings app -> Playgrounds -> turn on Authoring Debug Mode]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Does Authoring Debug Mode also show (or is there a way to get it to show) full errors on code or just errors with loading Playgrounds?  The only [resource](https://www.thecodehub.ie/news/2018/07/05/authoring-swift-playgrounds-subscription-feeds/) I could find talking about Authoring Debug Mode does so in the context of making a playground for distribution, but it is by no means comprehensive.  It would amazing if Authoring Debug Mode also works on the code itself.

Comment: I think authoring debug mode only shows compile errors, although I didn't try it myself. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247539/how-do-you-debug-swift-playgroundbook) shows a detailed error message for error compiling source but not for the runtime errors, if that's what you were asking.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for the clarification.  This is very useful.