# Defined a function as returning an optional but its returning a non optional

Tags: swift

In the following code why is expectingThisToBeOptional of type String and not of type String! when getOptional() is returning a String!

```
func getOptional() -> String!
{
    var s:String! = "Hello"
    return s
}


if let expectingThisToBeOptional = self.getOptional()
{
      // attempting to use expectingThisToBeOptional! gives error saying type is String not String!
}
else
{
    // why does execution come here when run?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if let` syntax unwraps the optional; the `else` block is executed when the optional is `nil`.

Also, optionals defined with `!` (rather than `?`) are "implicity unwrapped". Which means that you don't need to use the `myvar!` syntax (force unwrapping operator)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122601/swift-variable-decorations-with-and?noredirect=1#comment37533376_24122601) for more on the difference between an Optional (e.g., `String?`) and an implicitly unwrapped optional (e.g., `String!`)

Comment: In the question code the optional isn't nil, so why is the else branch still being executed?

Comment: @Sausages the question shows code which cannot possibly be all of the code in question - the function is called with a reference to `self` for instance. I suspect in his actual use the function (which I assume is a method) has more code than we're seeing, and does return nil sometimes. Because from what we can see it would never execute the else block.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an `if let` statement, the constant that you are setting contains the unwrapped value of the optional if it has a value. `self.getOptional()` return a `String!` which is unwrapped into a `String` and assigned to `expectingThisToBeOptional`.