# When will a variable be inferred as an implicitly unwrapped optional by Swift compiler?

Tags: swift

When will a variable be inferred as an implicitly unwrapped optional by Swift compiler? Or the variable has to always be declared with ! for it to be treated as such?

Comment: As far as I know, only `IBOutlets` are inferred to be implicitly unwrapped. Everything else needs to be declared with a `!`. The reason its called "implicitly unwrapped" is because you can access properties of it without unwrapping it first. Other than that it behaves identically to Optionals

Comment: Thanks Jack, useful bit on IBOutlet.  As far as it behaving identically as Optional, it can't contain nil though, right?

Comment: Yes it can, it is an "implicitly unwrapped Optional" which means its an Optional - just that when you access the properties, you don't have to unwrap it first. Thats about it..

Comment: Thanks Jack, can implicitly unwrapped optional participate in optional chaining like normal optional, using ?

Comment: Yes, like I said it behaves exactly like any other optional with one added difference

Answer (score 1):

The type inference occurs at compile time. The only way for a variable to be inferred as an implicitly unwrapped optional is to assign one to it (either directly, or by assigning the return value of a function, which returns an implicitly unwrapped optional).

Basically, the "optional-ness"  of a variable is *part* of it's type. The type of the following variables, `x` and `y` is `implicitly unwrapped Optional Int` (for both), and most importantly, the type system does not consider this the "same type" as `Int`. (Though you can use it interchangeably with an `Int` as long as it is not `nil`)

```
let x: Int! = 7

fund make_y() -> Int! {
  return 7
}

let y = make_y()
```

Comment: It's odd that it's called implicitly unwrapped when you have to specify !, it would seem like it should be called explicitly unwrapped?

Comment: You're explicit about it in the declaration, but throughout your code the unwrapping is implicit - no need for ! or ?.

Comment: It's called implicitly "unwrapped". In swift only optionals can be nil. Normally you have something like `var x: Int? = 7` and to get at the `7` you need to write `x!` (to unwrap it). by using the "implicitly unwrapped optional" you don't have to write `x!` to access the `7`, you just write `x`. I wrote a detailed explanation of the differences on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24122706/2908)

Comment: @Boon (forgot to mention you in the last one, oops!) To be "explicitly wrapped", it would be `Int?` (where you cannot access the value without using the forced unwrapping operator (i.e., `x!`)

Comment: Thanks Jiaaro.  ? is Optional<T> under the hood, what about implicitly unwrapped optional - is there a representation for it?

Comment: @Boon I don't know, sorry - It's possible that it also uses `Optional<T>`, but with an annotation to tell the compiler to automatically unwrap it.