# Error in Swift, need help: property 'self.circle1' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to programming and am getting this error in my Tic-tac-toe game: property `self.circle1` not initialized at `super.init` call.

I've already control-dragged and connected my `UIImage`s and buttons and all that and I've also tried taking the `strong` out of those statements (to make the outlet weak) and I'm still not able to run my app. What's going on? 
My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Initializing all imgs as variables:


@IBOutlet strong var circle1: UIImageView
@IBOutlet strong var circle2: UIImageView
@IBOutlet strong var circle3: UIImageView
@IBOutlet strong var circle4: UIImageView
@IBOutlet strong var circle5: UIImageView
@IBOutlet strong var circle6: UIImageView
@IBOutlet strong var circle7: UIImageView
@IBOutlet strong var circle8: UIImageView
@IBOutlet strong var circle9: UIImageView

@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn1: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn2: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn3: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn4: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn5: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn6: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn7: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn8: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var circleBtn9: UIButton

@IBOutlet strong var resetBtn: UIButton
@IBOutlet strong var ResultsLabel: UILabel

//Creating variables:

var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
var done = false
var aiDeciding = false

//Function that says what to do if a UIButton is clicked:

@IBAction func UIbuttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    ResultsLabel.hidden = true
    if !plays[sender.tag] && !aiDeciding && !done {
    setImgforCircle(sender.tag, player:1)

    }

//Executing these functions:

    checkforWin()
    aiTurn()

}

//Function that says sets an X or O in the proper circle depending on player:

func setImgforCircle(spot:Int, player:Int) {
    var playerMark = player == 1 ? "x" : "o"
    plays[spot] = player
    switch spot {
    case 1:
        circle1.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 2:
        circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 3:
        circle3.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 4:
        circle4.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 5:
        circle5.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 6:
        circle6.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 7:
        circle7.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 8:
        circle8.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 9:
        circle9.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

    default:
        circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    }

}

//Function that sees if certain paths of circles have the same mark

func checkforWin() {
var whoWon = ["Lost":0, "Won":1]
    for (key,value) in whoWon {
        if ((plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value && plays[3] == value) || //across top row
        (plays[4] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[6] == value) || //across middle row
        (plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[9] == value) || //across bottom row
        (plays[1] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[7] == value) || //down left column
        (plays[2] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[8] == value) || //down middle column
        (plays[3] == value && plays[6] == value && plays[9] == value) || //down right column
        (plays[1] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[9] == value) || //diagonal going right
        (plays[7] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[3] == value)) { //diagonal going left

            ResultsLabel.hidden = false
            ResultsLabel.text = "You \(key)!"
        }

    }

}
func aiTurn() {

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Definitely take the `strong`s out -- views are strongly held by their superview, so you want those vars to be weakly held by your view controller. You still get that same error without the `strong` declarations?

Comment: Not possible... definitely, same user, same question

Comment: Sorry, yes, by taking the "strong"s out the error is gone but I now get this message in a green bar at the top of my list of outlets: "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.4" when I try to run my app the simulator is just black.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's no reason to have all those `strong`s. Delete them. All.

Then, you should probably make all those optional if you don't want to initialize them in your init() method. So take a line like this:

```
@IBOutlet strong var circle1: UIImageView
```

And change it into this:

```
@IBOutlet var circle1: UIImageView!
```

[More information on the exclamation mark in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language).