# How are optional values implemented in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

I wonder how the value types in Swift (Int, Float...) are implemented to support optional binding ("?").
I assume those value types are not allocated on the heap, but on the stack. So, do they rely on some kind of pointer to the stack that may be null, or does the underlying struct contain a boolean flag ?

Comment: Bonus : whoever knowns the answer : how and where can we find such an answer for a given Swift seed (just in case of change in the future)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Optionals are implemented as `enum` type in Swift.

See [Apple's Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) for an example of how this is done:

```
enum OptionalValue<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)
}
```

Comment: Also, there is another type called `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`.

Comment: and then I guess the question would be... how are enums implemented? :)

Comment: I imagine that *tagged unions* are used which means that every value has a related tag stored with it. How else could you store a `Double?` ?

Answer (score 15):

Swift is open source since yesterday.
You can see the implementation on GitHub: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift

```
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral {

    case none
    case some(Wrapped)

    public init(_ some: Wrapped) { self = .some(some) }

    public init(nilLiteral: ()) {
        self = .none
    }

    public var unsafelyUnwrapped: Wrapped {
        get {
            if let x = self {
                return x
            }
            _debugPreconditionFailure("unsafelyUnwrapped of nil optional")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All this to use an `var theOptionalInt: Int?`?  Grossly inefficient compared to `int theInteger = 0;` or even `var theInteger: Integer = 0;` although thanks for posting Ugo... it’s kind of a shocker. Even AppleScript is more efficient. 

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers simply say that Swift optionals are implemented with `enum`s which begs the questions of how then is are `enum`s implemented. Something akin to *tagged unions* in C must be used. For example, the Swift enum

```
enum Foo {
  case None
  case Name(String)
  case Price(Double)
}
```

could be mimick'ed in C as follows:

```
enum {FOO_NONE_, FOO_NAME_, FOO_PRICE_};
typedef struct {
   int flavor; // FOO_NONE_, FOO_NAME_ or FOO_PRICE_
   union {
      char *Name;  // payload for FOO_STRING_
      double Price; // payload for FOO_DOUBLE_
   } u;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Optionals are implemented as shown below. To find this, CMD-Click on a declaration like `var x: Optional<Int>`. `var x: Int?` is just syntactic sugar for that.

```
enum Optional<T> : LogicValue, Reflectable {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    init()
    init(_ some: T)

    /// Allow use in a Boolean context.
    func getLogicValue() -> Bool

    /// Haskell's fmap, which was mis-named
    func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U?
    func getMirror() -> Mirror
}
```