# Why UIKit doesn't like Swift 3 optionals?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, option-type

The following *Swift 3* code crashes. The crash could be easily solved by either removing explicit optional type or by force unwrapping `view`. Could anyone explain **why** this code crashes?

```
let view: UIView? = UIView() // note the explicit *optional* type
_ = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 44.0)
```

*note: it won't compile with Swift 2.3 or lower*

Comment: This code doesn't crash. It won't compile.

Comment: Ah, I see you're doing this in Swift 3. In Swift 2 the first parameter was `AnyObject` (but not `AnyObject?`, like `item2` is) and would correctly warn you if you passed an optional. It's now `Any` (not `Any?` like `item2`). The compiler is clearly not warning us about the fact that the first parameter should not be optional. But it can't be optional, and clearly doesn't like it when you do try to pass an optional.

Comment: yes, I meant Swift 3 (Xcode 8). added note to the question

Comment: @Rob Do you know any docs which could explain how optionals are actually implemented? I used to think an optional is just a compile time check, like `__nullable` in ObjC, but it looks it's not.

Comment: @AlexanderVasenin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548475

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it crashes is `UIView` and `UIView?` are completely different types. `UIView` is **Objective-C class**, while `UIView?` is an **Swift enumeration** which can contain `UIView`. On the contrary, in Objective-C `nullable` is just a hint for compiler.

Comment: I got it, but how can we manage to stop crashes because of this reason?

Comment: @Steve You must unwrap optional to use it with UIKit

Answer (score 4):

`NSLayoutConstraint(item:, attribute:, relatedBy:, toItem:, attribute:, multiplier:, constant:)` has an `item` parameter typed as `Any`:

```
public convenience init(item view1: Any, attribute attr1: NSLayoutAttribute, relatedBy relation: NSLayoutRelation, toItem view2: Any?, attribute attr2: NSLayoutAttribute, multiplier: CGFloat, constant c: CGFloat)
```

But from the crash you can glean that the parameter can really only accept `UIView` or `UILayoutGuide`:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for Optional(UIView: 0x7fa0fbd06650; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = CALayer: 0x60800003bb60): Constraint **items must each be an instance of UIView, or UILayoutGuide**.'

The compiler can't check for the type of `item` during compile time. It is defined to accept anything. But in the implementation details that are inaccessible to us, that method accepts only non-optional `UIView`s or `UILayoutGuide`s.

So just add a `guard` statement:

```
let view: UIView? = UIView()
guard let view = view else { // Proceed only if unwrapped
  fatalError()
}
let _ = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 44.0)
```