# Why do these methods return "String!" and not "String"?

Tags: arrays, cocoa-touch, swift, dictionary

I am currently trying to save an Array of Dictionaries to NSUserDefaults. I originally planned to have the type be `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>` but that does not appear to be the case here. 
To start, I am getting the String values from the following UI objects:

```
@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var instructor: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var time: UIDatePicker!
```

And then saving it into a Dictionary like so:

```
let values = ["name" : self.name.text, "instructor" : self.instructor.text, "date" : self.time.date.description]
```

However the Dictionary's type is inferred as `Array<Dictionary<String,String!>>` not `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>`. The problem seems to be that `self.name.text` and `self.instructor.text` returns **String!**, but `self.time.date.description` returns **String**.

I think it would be possible to ignore these and continue on, but I want to understand what is going on here rather than continue and hope it doesn't break something in the future.

Comment: This may help:
[What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to iOS Developer Library, a `UITextField` `text` property, returns a `!String` ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/text)). The `description` in `self.time.date.description` represents a date object as `String` ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDate/description)) and is common used for debugging (a better practice to represent a NSDate object as a `String` is to use a [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html))