# Swift Optionals(?). What's the difference between two?

Tags: swift, syntax, null, optional-parameters, option-type

In terms of the optionals(?), what's the difference between the two?
I'm trying to pick up swift and it seems that the location of "?" matters and i'm having a hard time grasping the effect of having "?" in different places.

```
    var beaconGroup:GroupData = filteredArray.firstObject? as GroupData

    var beaconGroup:GroupData = filteredArray.firstObject as GroupData
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

Comment: Actually there is no difference between both. The second is just a shorter form (syntactic sugar) of the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between those two lines:

```
var beaconGroup:GroupData = filteredArray.firstObject? as GroupData

var beaconGroup:GroupData = filteredArray.firstObject as GroupData
```

In the first, the `?` is unnecessary — `firstObject` already returns an Optional. Using the optional chaining operator without actually chaining a further member lookup or access expression has no effect.

In Swift 1.2 (currently available in the Xcode 6.3 beta), superfluous use of the optional chaining operator is a compile error:

> error: optional chain has no effect, operation already produces 'AnyObject?'

Answer (score 1):

An optional in Swift is a variable that can hold either a value or no value. Optionals are written by appending a ? to the type:

```
var myOptionalString:String? = "Hello"
```

`?` are used in two normal ways:

1.Declare a optional var (just add `?` after the type)

```
var strValue : String?
```

2.To judge var will respond to the methods or properties while being called

```
let hashValue = strValue?.hashValue
```

If `strValue` is nil, `hashValue` is nil. If `strValue` not nil, thus `hashValue` is the value of `strValue`.