# Using variables in Filters in SQLite.swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sqlite.swift

I am using `SQLite.swift (Branch Swift-1-2)` in my app in XCode 6.3 beta.
I am able to create the Database/Tables and insert entries into the tables.

So far so good.

Now when I have a simple scenario as follows:

```
class Foo {
   var id: Int?
   var name: String?
   /* constructor to create an instance ... */
}

// This is how the table column is defined
var id = Expression<Int64>("id")

// Function to update data in the table
func updateFoo(foo: Foo) -> Int? {
    // 'foos' is the table name
    let candidateFoo = foos.filter(super.id == foo.id!) //<----ERROR!!!
    let (rowsUpdated, statement) = candidateFoo.update(name <- foo.name!)

    if  let rowsUpdated = rowsUpdated {
        println("Succesfully updated \(rowsUpdated) row(s)")
        return rowsUpdated
    } else if statement.failed {
        println("Update failed. Reason: \(statement.reason)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

On the line commented `\\ <----ERROR!!!`, I get the compile-time error:
**Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type Expression< Int64 > and Int**

If I use an `Int` directly on that line, then that works fine. Eg.

```
let candidateFoo = foos.filter(super.id == 3) // No Error!
```

But, if I simply do this, it fails with the same error again:

```
var i = 3
let candidateFoo = foos.filter(super.id == i) // <----ERROR!!!
```

I understand what the error is, but I am not able to resolve it. I looked at the [documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/swift-1-2/Documentation/Index.md#sqliteswift-documentation) but I am still stuck. So any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

Explicitly declaring the variable as Int64 solves the issue:

```
var i:Int64 = 3
let candidateFoo = foos.filter(super.id == i) // No Error!
```

Now I am wondering if I have to change my class definition, which will require changes at multiple places in the code. Also [official swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/NumericTypes.html) recommends using Int unless an explicit size is required.

> You should use the word-sized Int type to store integer values, unless
>   you require a type with a specific size or signedness.

Also, the SQLite.swift documentation states that:

> While Int64 is the basic, raw type (to preserve 64-bit integers on
>   32-bit platforms), Int and Bool work transparently.

So should I be using the `Int64` here explicitly in my class definition, since its mapped to a DB?

Comment: I thought this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054958/why-do-i-have-to-explicitly-unwrap-my-string-in-this-case

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue. I understand (I think!) the difference between `id?`, `id!` and `id = 3`. See my update above. Even if I declare a  local `var i = 3` and use it in the `filter()` I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mapping your `Foo` structure directly to the underlying types in SQL, so you should use the same type in both places. If you need 64-bit precision on 32-bit devices (to avoid overflow, etc.), you should use `Int64`. If you're not worried, use `Int` both places:

```
var id = Expression<Int>("id")
```

> If I use an Int directly on that line, then that works fine. Eg.

This is because that's actually an `Int64`, which conforms to `IntegerLiteralConvertible` so the literal's underlying type is inferred (you can read more about Swift's literal convertibles here: http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/).

> So should I be using the Int64 here explicitly in my class definition, since its mapped to a DB?

Keep in mind that the SQLite.swift expression layer gives you the flexibility to refer to the underlying column types however you want to (assuming you [conform it to its `Value` protocol](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#custom-types)), so again: you can use `Int` freely if that's how you're treating the value throughout your code.

Beyond all this, when you work with different integer types in Swift, you can cast them inline. *E.g.*,

```
let candidateFoo = foos.filter(super.id == Int64(foo.id!))
```

Comment: This clarifies my exact point of confusion! Thanks for the answer!