# Cannot convert value of type 'Int64?' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: swift, casting, int, int64

When I try to pass job?.id (an Int64) as Int parameter ( while I know it's not that big ), swift compiler prompts with this error, I tried a couple of ways to cast it, but had no success :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int64?' to expected argument type 'Int'
```

My code :

```
Job.updateJobStatus(token: tok, jobId: job?.id, status:JobSatus.canceled) { (result, error) in
        if result != nil
        {

        }
        else if error != nil
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793656/8236481

Comment: Ignoring the optional issue for the moment, why are the two id data types different?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793460/can-i-cast-int64-directly-into-int

Comment: @Oxthor Thanks, worked, please post it as answer so I accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793656/8236481

> Swift 3 introduces failable initializers to safely convert one integer type to another. By using init?(exactly:) you can pass one type to initialize another, and it returns nil if the initialization fails. The value returned is an optional which must be unwrapped in the usual ways.

```
Int(exactly: yourInt64)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can easily go like:

```
let int64Value: Int64 = 123456
let intValue = NSNumber(value: int64Value).intValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues to solve. First you need to deal with `job` being optional. Then you need to deal with `job.id` being a different data type than the `jobId` parameter.

You have lots of options for the optional issue:

```
guard let job = job else { return }

Job.updateJobStatus(token: tok, jobId: Int(job.id), status:JobSatus.canceled) { (result, error) in
    if let result = result {
    } else if let error = error {
    }
}
```

Or you can fallback to a default value:

```
Job.updateJobStatus(token: tok, jobId: Int(job?.id ?? 0), status:JobSatus.canceled) { (result, error) in
    if let result = result {
    } else if let error = error {
    }
}
```

Please note that you really should just make the `jobId` parameter have the same data type as the `id` property. The conversion from `Int64` to `Int` can fail if the value is too large to be converted.