# Objective C long bridged to Swift as int?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I can't bridge ObjectiveC long type into Swift.

```
//Swift
typealias Long = Int64
struct Item: Equatable {
    let itemId: Long
    ...
}

//ObjC
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) long itemId;

//Try create object in Swift
Item(itemId: objCObject.itemId)
```

Error:
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Long' (aka 'Int64')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I cast Int64 directly into Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793460/can-i-cast-int64-directly-into-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (Objective-)C type `long` is bridged to Swift as [`CLong`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/clong) which is an alias for the Swift `Int` type. `Int` can be a 32-bit or 64-bit integer, depending on the platform.

In any case, you cannot cast or assign an `Int64` directly to an `Int`, see also [Can I cast Int64 directly into Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793460/can-i-cast-int64-directly-into-int).

If you want to keep the Swift `itemID` as a `Int64` then you'll have to convert it to `CLong` when calling the Objective-C method. Alternatively you can change the Swift type to make it compatible:

```
struct Item: Equatable {
    let itemId: CLong
    ...
}
```

Another option would be to change the Objective-C type to

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) int64_t itemId;
```

which is then imported to Swift as `Int64`.