# Swift enum loses initialized values when set as a property?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I've found a work-around, but this problem is vexing me and I thought I'd share in case anyone else is having the same problem.  Would love to know why this is happening.  In the code below, I can switch on the enum just fine during the class initializer when it's a local variable.  I store the enum value into a property.  But when I try to switch on the stored property (named foo) in a different method (named bar()) in the example below - I get compiler warnings and an error that the member(s) are not recognized.  It seems to know that foo is a MyEnum type, but doesn't know that .ABC, .DEF, and .GHI are members.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case ABC, DEF, GHI
}

class MyClass : NSObject {

    var foo : MyEnum!

    convenience init(foo: MyEnum) {

        self.init()

        self.foo = foo

        switch foo {

        case .ABC: println("ABC foo")
        case .DEF: println("DEF foo")
        case .GHI: println("GHI foo")
        default: println("no foo")

        }
    }

    func bar() {

        switch foo {

        case .ABC: println("ABC foo")
        case .DEF: println("DEF foo")
        case .GHI: println("GHI foo")
        default: println("no foo")

        }
    }
}
```

The workaround is to either say:

```
switch foo as MyEnum { }
```

or declare a local variable in the method like

```
let x : MyEnum = foo

switch x {  }
```

Again, glad I found a workaround, but would sure like to know if this is the expected behavior or if a radar needs to be filed with Apple.  This is Xcode 6.2, BTW.

Comment: Reason is that `MyEnum` and `MyEnum!` are different types.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language Either you have to unwrap `foo` in `bar()`, or use normal property (and not implicitly unwrapped one).

Answer (score 4):

Property `foo` is not `MyEnum`, but `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<MyEnum>` aka `MyEnum!`. Unlike many other cases, `switch` does not implicitly unwrap it.

You have to unwrap it manually:

```
    if let foo = foo {
        switch foo {
        case .ABC: println("ABC foo")
        case .DEF: println("DEF foo")
        case .GHI: println("GHI foo")
        default: println("no foo")
        }
    }
    else {
        println("nil foo")
    }
```

OR force unwrap with `!` if you are sure `foo` is not `nil`, :

```
    switch foo! {
    case .ABC: println("ABC foo")
    case .DEF: println("DEF foo")
    case .GHI: println("GHI foo")
    default: println("no foo")
    }
```

OR match with `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Enum>` as is:

```
    switch foo {
    case .Some(.ABC): println("ABC foo")
    case .Some(.DEF): println("DEF foo")
    case .Some(.GHI): println("GHI foo")
    default: println("no foo")
    }
```

Comment: Ah, the implicitly unwrapped optional.  Haven't checked it out in code, but it makes sense.  Thanks!