# Swift 2 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Error found from this line:
self.picture.image = UIImage(named: pictures[closestBeacon.minor.integerValue]!)

How to solve?

Comment: Read this: [Apple Swift Documentation, The Basics: Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

Comment: Probably your `pictures` array contains nil at `closestBeacon.minor.integerValue` index. You should read articles metioned above

Comment: Question shows no effort. Please explain what effort was made in attempting to resolve the issue prior to posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the crash by safely unwrapping pictures[closetBeacon.minor.integerValue] with an if let statement.

```
if let myImage = pictures[closetBeacon.minor.integerValue] {
self.picture.image = UIImage(named: myImage)
```

}