# iOS 9 - Swift - Writing data to a FileStorage - word "Optional" is prefixed for every field

Tags: ios, swift, csv, option-type, nsfilehandle

Trying to write data from UI to IOS File Storage :

```
 @IBAction func savetoFile(sender: AnyObject) {
        let csvLine:String="\(bookName.text), \(bookAuthor.text),\(bookIsbn.text)\n"
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,
            NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let docDir:String=paths[0] as String
        let bookFile:String=(docDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("bookresults.dat")

        if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(bookFile) {
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(bookFile,
                contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        }

        let fileHandle:NSFileHandle=NSFileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath:bookFile)!
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.writeData(csvLine.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        fileHandle.closeFile()
```

Problem :

If I give "BookOne" , program writes to file as "Optional("BookOne") and repeats this "Optional" for every field , every row.

Appreciate if someone could share the fix with code for this problem.

Tech stack is Xcode 7.1 and SWIFT.

Thanks

Comment: That is because, the 'text' field is optional on your bookName, bookAuthor, bookIsBn, etc. Try unwrapping them, and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks Shripada .. I appended every text field with a '!' to unwrap and it fixed the problem .

Comment: Appending ! is not a good idea. It is a crash waiting to happen. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33399973/239816

Answer (score 1):

If `foo` is an optional type (`String?`, for example), then string interpolation puts that annoying `Optional(...)` wrapper around it. (That’s a language design mistake IMO — interpolation should either unwrap automatically or not accept optionals — but Apple did it the way they did it!)

To get rid of the `Optional(...)`, you need to make the thing inside the `\()` not be optional. There are many ways of doing that.

One is to use default values:

```
"\(bookName.text ?? ""), \(bookAuthor.text ?? ""), etc"
```

(This assumes you want nil to come out as an empty string.)

The expression `bookName.text ?? ""` cannot evaluate to nil, so its type is `String` and not `String?`, and the `Optional(...)` wrapper goes away. You could even put that in a helper:

```
func emptyIfNil(string: String?) -> String {
    return string ?? ""
}

"\(emptyIfNil(bookName.text)), \(emptyIfNil(bookAuthor.text)), etc"
```

Another approach is to use `if let` to unwrap the optionals:

```
if let name = bookNext.text, let author = bookAuthor.text, ...etc... {
    let csvLine:String="\(name), \(author),\(isbn)\n"
    ...
}
```

This would only output rows where all the values are present.

A tidy approach in your case is to use sequence operations, and avoid interpolation altogether:

```
let csvLine = [bookName, bookAuthor, bookIsbn]
    .map { $0.text ?? "" }
    .joinWithSeparator(",")
```

I strongly **recommend against using `!`** to unwrap the optionals in this (and most) situations. Saying `bookName.text!` means, “if `bookName.text` is nil, that is such a terribly calamity that the best thing to do is to crash the whole app.” If there is *any* reasonable behavior for the case when `bookName.text` is nil — and I imagine in your case there is — then you should code for it instead of allowing the possibility of that crash.