# Fatal Error with Swift on Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, fatal-error

I have been struggling with this for a while. I am trying to have a UIWebview and I keep getting a fatal error which is as follows "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)". Then in my code it says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode 0x0". I do not understand why I keep getting this. Also, I am very new to coding. I will post the code below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var WebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")

        WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: it is crashing on WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))

Comment: In order to code in Swift you *have* to understand how Optionals work. Read the Swift manual. // Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language. Either your IBOutlet or your URL is nil.

Comment: try `print(WebView)` right before the crashing line - what does it yield?

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause is that you forgot (or lost) the link to your IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

The above code works fine for me. Make sure that you properly connected the IBOutlet.
[image: My code]

And also make sure that you added App Transport Security in your plist. Like below screenshot
[image: plist]