# Swift Addition: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (Code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-playground

I'm trying to add two numbers in Swift and print its sum

```
import Foundation

func solveMefirst(firstNo: Int , secondNo: Int) -> Int {
    return firstNo + secondNo
}

let num1 = readLine()
let num2 = readLine()

var IntNum1 = Int(num1!) ** Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (Code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). **
var IntNum2 = Int(num2!)

let sum = solveMefirst(IntNum1!, secondNo: IntNum2!)
print(sum)
```

But unfortunately this error comes out and stops the execution in playground.

```
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (Code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

[image]

Could not understand, what is wrong in this?

**UPDATE**

Also please explain how to run this command line program in playground?

How can I take input from playground??.

Comment: `num1` and `num2` are nil as you can clearly see in the output - what is supposed to happen when you unwrap them?

Comment: You should read [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language), it will help a lot.

Comment: @EricD.  can u please explain how to take STDIN input in playground

Answer (score 2):

I ran it using command line. I think you are using play ground but you didn't take input for num1 and num2.
After running the project take input for number 1 then press enter. Then take input for number two and press enter. It will give you the desired result. Your code is working fine. I run it here.

[image: Output of Command Line Based Project]

Comment: Positive suggestions are always appreciated :)

Comment: can you tell me how to run this code in playgrounds?

Comment: If you want to take input from user its better to switch on console based application in Xcode. Furthermore its mentioned in Raywenderlich tutorial that playground doesn't allow input from user:
[Reference Tutorial of RayWenderlich:](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114173/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-2-your-first-project)

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because you force a nil value which results in an error;
As you can read on the left `num1= nil`. **It don't know what it is supposed to be but there is the error.** Because when you try to force a value to `num1`(that's what "!" does) it crashes because `num1` has no value.

Comment: yes, maybe thats why the error was showing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION