# How to take STDIN in Swift playground

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, swift-playground

I know that to program in STDIN and STDOUT, we need to make an command line project in Xcode. 
But how do I take a standard input in playground.

Whenever I try to run such code in playground

```
var input = readLine()!
```

I always get this error

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (Code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Is it possible to take STDIN in playground or not?

**UPDATE**

I know this error is because of **nil** `input` variable but want to know how to overcome this nil value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Addition: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC\_BAD\_INSTRUCTION (Code=EXC\_l386\_INVOP, subcode=0x0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347755/swift-addition-execution-was-interrupted-reason-exc-bad-instruction-code-exc)

Comment: no its not - I'm expecting how to take STDIN in playgrounds, that question is a bit different. @HenrikGustafsson

Comment: You can't at this stage as far as I have tested. You have to create a command line tool. Or you could create a playground with a "Singe View" add a UITextView an enter button and do it that way. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

**Fixed Solution for SWIFT 3**

To make it work, Create a new command line tool project.

Go to "File" -> "New" -> "Project" -> "macOS" -> "Command Line Tool".

```
import Foundation

print("Hello, World!")


func solveMefirst(firstNo: Int , secondNo: Int) -> Int {
    return firstNo + secondNo
}

func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = FileHandle.standardInput
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
}

let num1 = readLine()
let num2 = readLine()

var IntNum1 = Int(num1!)
var IntNum2 = Int(num2!)

print("Addition of numbers is :  \(solveMefirst(firstNo: IntNum1!, secondNo: IntNum2!))")
```

And run the project using `CMD + R`

Answer (score 4):

Playground can not read an input from the commend line.

You can use a custom "readLine()" function and a global input variable, each element in the input array is presenting a line:

```
import Foundation

var currentLine = 0
let input = ["5", "5 6 3"]

func readLine() -> String? {
    if currentLine < input.endIndex {
        let line = input[currentLine]
        currentLine += 1
        return line
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

let firstLine = readLine() //  5
let secondLine = readLine() // 5 6 3
let thirdLine = readLine() // nil
```

Comment: This is a great solution for use on sites like HackerRank when you are using a Xcode Playground to work on your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html):

```
if let input = readLine() {
    print("Input: \(input)")
} else {
    print("No input.")
}
```

Comment: Obviously this will print "No input.\n" in playground. But it cannot be the answer for my question. Yes it was nice trick

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to use standard input from playground. This is just a way of working around the nil issue.

It should work once you run it outside of playground though.

Comment: can you tell me why this code works   `var input = readLine()` and why not this `var input = readLine()!` in playground.

Comment: @VinodRathod in my playground (Xcode 7.2.1) it 'runs forewer' (so readLine doesn't return)

Answer (score 0):

Go to

New > Project > MacOs > Command Line Tool

then you can apply :

let value1: String?

```
value1 = readLine()
print(value1 ?? "")
```

"" for the default value

Answer (score 0):

```
private var lines: IndexingIterator<[String]>?

public var file: String? {
    didSet {
        lines = file?.split(separator: "\n").map(String.init).makeIterator()
    }
}

public func readLine() -> String? {
    lines?.next()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For getting input from command line, like Console.ReadLine... *Chalkers* has a solution as follows.

```
func input() -> String {
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
}
```

please ask for further if it doesn't work Vinod.

Comment: no this function input() is same as readLine(). I'm concerned about how to get the standard input from user in playground