# What is the actual meaning of " ! " prefix in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, setediting

I want to know about prefix `!`. I have created an app, and it has `tableView`. And I have used `setEditing:animated` property for editing a `tableView`, it allows multiple selection. When user start selecting? We need to cancel segue operations. Of course we need to override `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method. Here's my code

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return !editing
    }
```

Firstly I've tried to use `return editing`. Xcode does not gave me any errors even run time errors. Everything seems to works just fine. But segues are still works. And then I've tried to use with prefix  `return !editing`. Works perfect! What's the actual meaning of this prefix `!` ?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!` operator is the logical NOT of a boolean value; i.e. `!true` becomes `false`, `!false` becomes `true`.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks very much!