# What's different between ? and ! in weak, strong reference in Swift

Tags: swift, reference, null, weak

I'm beginner in **Swift**. I have some questions need to resolve but I can't do it by myself.

Here is some problem for me:

```
class Author {
    weak var book: Book?        
    deinit {
        print("Dealloc Author")
    }
}

class Book {
    var author: Author?        
    deinit {
        print("Dealloc Book")
    }
}

var authorObj:Author? = Author()
authorObj!.book = Book()
authorObj!.book!.author = authorObj
```

This compiles fine:

```
class Author {
    weak var book: Book?        
    deinit {
        print("Dealloc Author")
    }
}

class Book {
    var author: Author?        
    deinit {
        print("Dealloc Book")
    }
}

var authorObj:Author? = Author()
authorObj!.book = Book()
authorObj!.book?.author = authorObj

authorObj = nil
```

- So can you guys explain for me, what's different between ? and ! in `authorObj!.book?.author = authorObj` and 
  `authorObj!.book!.author = authorObj`?

I have two more questions:

- `authorObj` is a strong reference same as `authorObj.book.author`, it's strong reference too? Because it dont have `weak` or `unowned` before var.
- Only `authorObj.book` is weak reference. But when I assign `authorObj` to nil, all are deinited. Why? I assign only `authorObj` to nil but `Author()` instance still have 1 strong reference `authorObj.book.author`

Comment: it is considered a better practice to paste code directly into the question rather than giving a link to a picture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @HungNguyen.  I edited your question to post the actual code instead of a picture.  Please post your actual code in the future as it allows others to try your code more easily.  If my answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it to turn it green.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: @vacawama thank you! I got it. Sorry for my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So can you guys explain for me, what's different between ? and ! in
>   authorObj!.book?.author = authorObj and  authorObj!.book!.author =
>   authorObj?

When you use `?` to unwrap an optional it is referred to as *optional chaining*.  If the optional is `nil`, the result of the entire chain will be `nil`.  The advantage of using `?` is that your app won't crash if the value being unwrapped is `nil`.

So:

```
authorObj!.book?.author = authorObj
```

will crash if `authorObj` is `nil` (because of the *forced unwrap* `!`).

and:

```
authorObj!.book!.author = authorObj
```

will crash if either `authorObj` or `book` is `nil`.

The *safe* way to write this would be:

```
authorObj?.book?.author = authorObj
```

If `authorObj` or `book` is `nil`, this will do nothing *and* it won't crash.

> authorObj is a strong reference same as authorObj.book.author, it's
>   strong reference too? Because it dont have weak or unowned before var.

It only makes sense to talk about a single variable when talking about *weak* vs. *strong*.  It doesn't make sense to ask if `authorObj.book` is *weak*; you can say that `Author` holds a *weak* reference to `book`.

> Only authorObj.book is weak reference. But when I assign authorObj to
>   nil, all are deinited. Why? I assign only authorObj to nil but
>   Author() instance still have 1 strong reference authorObj.book.author

When you assign `nil` to `authorObj`, that was the last strong reference to `authorObj`, so *Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)* decrements the reference counter and then frees all of the references inside of `authorObj`.  If those are *strong* references, it decrements the reference count and if that was the last reference to that object, the object is freed as well.  If any other object is holding a *weak* reference to any object that is freed, then *ARC* will set that value to `nil` in all of the *weak* pointers.

---

To test this in a playground, put your commands inside a function called `test` and add `print` statements so that you can see when things happen.

```
class Author {
    weak var book: Book?

    deinit {
        print("Dealloc Author")
    }
}

class Book {
    var author: Author?

    deinit {
        print("Dealloc Book")
    }
}

func test() {
    print("one")
    var authorObj: Author? = Author()
    print("two")
    authorObj!.book = Book()
    print("three")
    authorObj!.book?.author = authorObj
    print("four")
}

test()
```

Output:

> ```
> one
> two
> Dealloc Book
> three
> four
> Dealloc Author
> ```

The thing to note is that the `Book` is deallocated before step `three`.  Why? Because there are no *strong* pointers to it.  You allocated it and then assigned the only reference to it to a *weak* pointer inside of *Author*, so *ARC* immediately freed it.

That explains why `authorObj!.book!.author = authorObj` crashes, because `authorObj!.book` is `nil` since the `Book` which was just assigned to it has been freed.

---

Now, try assigning `Book()` to a local variable `book`:

```
func test() {
    print("one")
    var authorObj: Author? = Author()
    print("two")
    let book = Book()
    authorObj!.book = book
    print("three")
    authorObj!.book?.author = authorObj
    print("four")
    authorObj = nil
    print("five")
}

test()
```

This time, the output is quite different:

> ```
> one
> two
> three
> four
> five
> Dealloc Book
> Dealloc Author
> ```

Now, the local variable `book` holds a *strong* reference to the `Book` that was allocated, so it doesn't get immediately freed.

Note, even though we assigned `nil` to `authorObj` in step `four`, it wasn't deallocated until after `book` was deallocated after step `five`.

The local variable `book` holds a *strong* reference to `Book()`, and `Book` holds a *strong* reference to `Author`, so when we assign `nil` to `authorObj` in step `four`, the `authorObj` can't be freed because `book` still holds a *strong* reference to it.  When `test` ends, the local variable `book` is freed, so the *strong* reference to `authorObj` is freed, and finally `authorObj` can be deallocated since the last *strong* reference to it is gone.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it!