# Binding must have Optional type Swift 3 Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm interested why I'm getting this error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not [String]

Here is my code:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var typesField: IQDropDownTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let elements: Array<String?> = ["Electronics", "Cars", "Toys"]
        typesField.isOptionalDropDown = false
        typesField.itemList = (elements as? [String])!    
    }

    @IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var item: Item!

        if let types = typesField.itemListUI {
            item.type = types
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is actually causing the error?

Comment: if let types = typesField.itemListUI { -> this one

Comment: whenever you use `if let` the right side *must* be an **optional** (which may or may not have a value). For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language/38830543#38830543). **Non-optionals** may not ever be `nil` so *for sure* it has a value; in your case the value *is* a `string` and isn't `string?`. You can just write that line as `types = typesField.itemListUI` —without the `if let`.

Comment: you mean `let types = typesField.itemListUI` - because at first I have to create variable `types `

Comment: You could have just skipped that line and just done : `item.type = typesField.itemListUI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not [String]

means the right side of the expression (`typesField.itemListUI`) is not optional and the optional binding is not needed

So instead

```
if let types = typesField.itemListUI {
   item.type = types
}
```

just write

```
item.type = typesField.itemListUI
```

No `if let`, no extra local variable.

Comment: I'm getting this error — Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'

Comment: Apparently `item.type` is declared as (single) `String` not as array of `String` (`[String]`). You have to resolve this in your design.