# why (self.account.text?.isEmpty)! is required '!'

Tags: swift, option-type

```
    if (self.account.text?.isEmpty)! {


    }
```

I just write down this function in ViewDidLoad().
(account is a textfield)

I think that 'self.account.text' can be nil, and 'self.account.text?' is okay.
but I don't know why 'self.account.text?.isEmpty' require '!' - unwrapping.

'self.account.text?.isEmpty' is right, isn't it....?

I always appreciate all answers.

Comment: This is because you have 3 different possible results: true, false or nil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the expression `self.account.text?.isEmpty` has a value of type `bool` or the value `nil`, and you can't use `nil` as an if-condition.

Using `!` here is wrong. If `text` is `nil` then the code will crash.

Instead write:

```
if self.account.text?.isEmpty == true { ... }
// or equivalently:
if self.account.text?.isEmpty ?? false { ... }
```

if you want to skip the if when `text` is `nil`, or:

```
if self.account.text?.isEmpty != false { ... }
// or equivalently:
if self.account.text?.isEmpty ?? true { ... }
```

if you want to enter the if when `text` is `nil`.

If `text` should never be `nil` here then you can just use `!` directly after `text`:

```
if self.account.text!.isEmpty { ... }
```

Comment: For better readability don't use nil coalescing operator  with optional chaining `Bool?` types just use `== true` or `== false` or `== nil`.

Comment: Actually, I prefer remove the optional as soon as possible instead of propagating optionals further in the expression: `(self.account.text ?? "").isEmpty`.

Comment: then, which circumstances does the .isEmpty become nil?

Comment: @JKU The value of `isEmpty` is never `nil`. But the value of the expression `self.account.text?.isEmpty` is `nil` when `text` is `nil`, i.e. the evaluation of `isEmpty` is skipped in that case.

Comment: @Sulthan Don't use nil coalescence to provide a default value, only to depend on some property of that default value. (e.g. you're relying on `?? ""` to make `isEmpty` be `true` when `text` is `nil`). Instead, just use map: `self.account.text.map{ $0.isEmpty }`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.account.text
```

is optional boolean value so it will be nil or boolean. unwrapping the boolean must check it is equal to true or false like in this way.otherwise it will crash because of nil value.

```
import UIKit
var isempty: Bool?

if isempty == true
{
   print("i am empty")
}
else
{
   print("hy i am not empty")
}
//it will print "Hy i am not empty" because isempty has nil
```