# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Todo?.Type'

Tags: swift, option-type

Working on a tutorial thats a little old and need help figuring out how to initialize without optional types

```
var resultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Todo>!
let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Request
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Todo> = Todo.fetchRequest()
    let sortDesriptors = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)

    //Init
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDesriptors]
    resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: request,
        managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil)

    resultsController.delegate = self
    //Fetch
    do {
        try resultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Perfom fetch error: \(error)")
    }


}


var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
var todo = Todo?

if let todo = todo {                 <--- same issue here
    textView.text = todo.title
    textView.text = todo.title
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = Int(todo.priority)




if let todo = todo {                 //<-- need help here.
    todo.title = title
    todo.priority = Int16(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
} else {
    let todo = Todo(context: managedContext)
    todo.title = title
    todo.priority = Int16(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    todo.date = Date()
}
```

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Todo?.Type'

keep getting this error message

Comment: What is `Todo`? Can you show the code where `Todo` was created?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to initialize `todo` via `var todo = Todo(parameter1Name: Parameter1Type, parameter2Name: Parameter2Type)`. You could also declare an optional instance of `Todo` via `var todo: Todo?` or implicitly unwrapped optional via `var todo: Todo!` and set this value later. Optional types can be understood here: [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

```swift
var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

//Option 1:
var todo = Todo()

//Option 2:
var optionalTodo: Todo?

optionalTodo = Todo()

if let todo = todo {
    textView.text = todo.title
    textView.text = todo.title
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = Int(todo.priority)
    todo.title = title
    todo.priority = Int16(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
} else {
    let todo = Todo(context: managedContext)
    todo.title = title
    todo.priority = Int16(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    todo.date = Date()
}
```

Comment: Also note that in the `else`, you probably don't want the `let`. That creates yet another variable named `todo` and it does not set the `todo` property.

Comment: Good call, I hadn’t looked much at what was inside the conditionals